# find code from one list to another using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a response object with 8 json string in each. Each have a exterior color with code that i need to match from one another. I have the code working with two for loops. I would like to use streams and be more efficient. I cant seem to figure it out.

In the response object there are 8 json strings that i am looping over.

In my merge method, i am passing in an empty list and a lookupresponse object
and the style id found in the vehicle array. The first thing i do is assign the first temp list to the empty list i am passing in as my first parameter. Ultimately i am using that first initial list to match exteriorColors.code and if they match i add the styleid to the styles array in the exteriorcolors.
if its not found than i add the whole color object to the initial list and keep checking.

lookup response class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class LookupResponse implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1079274125000921996L;

private List<VehicleInfo> vehicles;
private List<Packages> packages;
private List<TechSpecs> techSpecs;
private List<Features> features;
private List<Color> exteriorColors;
private List<Color> interiorColors;
private List<OptionsMSRP> options;
```

}

```
    for(int i = 0; i < cResponse.getResult().size(); i++){
        String val = cResponse.getResult().get(i).get(VEH_SUMMARY_RESPONSE);
        temp = mapper.readValue(val, LookupResponse.class);
        vehicles.add(temp.getVehicles().get(0));
      exteriorColors = mergeColors(exteriorColors, temp.getExteriorColors(), temp.getVehicles().get(0).getStyleId());

}


 private List<Color> mergeColors(List<Color> mergeList, List<Color> lstExterior, String styleid) {

    List<String> styles =  new ArrayList<>();
    boolean isColorFound = false;

    for(int idx = 0; idx < lstExterior.size(); idx++){
        styles.clear();
        styles.add(styleid);
        lstExterior.get(idx).setStyles(styles);
        isColorFound = false;
        if(mergeList.size() == 0){
            mergeList.add(lstExterior.get(idx));

        }else{
            for(int idx2 = 0; idx2 < mergeList.size(); idx2++){
                if(mergeList.get(idx2).getCode().equalsIgnoreCase(lstExterior.get(idx).getCode())){
                    if(!mergeList.get(idx2).getStyles().contains(styleid)){
                        mergeList.get(idx2).getStyles().add(styleid);
                    }
                    isColorFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!isColorFound){
                mergeList.add(lstExterior.get(idx));
            }
        }
    }

    return mergeList;

}
```

I am trying to use java 8 streams / lambda to acheive the same result. I need some help.
what i have tried and it doesnt work is

```
 private List<Color> mergeColors(List<Color> mergeList, List<Color> lstExterior, String styleid) {

    List<String> styles =  new ArrayList<>();
    List<Color> filteredList =  new ArrayList<>();
    boolean isColorFound = false;

    for(int idx = 0; idx < lstExterior.size(); idx++){
        styles.clear();
        styles.add(styleid);
        lstExterior.get(idx).setStyles(styles);
        isColorFound = false;
        if(mergeList.size() == 0){
            mergeList.add(lstExterior.get(idx));

        }else{

            filteredList = mergeList.stream()
                    .filter(ml -> lstExterior.stream()
                            .allMatch(lst -> lst.getCode().equals(ml.getCode())))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

        }
    }

    return mergeList;

}
```

but theres only the first item in there. I am lost. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with rewriting code inside `else`, from this place:

```
for(int idx2 = 0; idx2 < mergeList.size(); idx2++){
```

This for can be replaced with stream to find the first element that match:

```
String lstExteriorCode = lstExterior.get(idx).getCode();
Optional<Color> firstMatch = mergeList.stream()
  .filter(ml -> ml.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase(lstExteriorCode))
  .findFirst();
```

With `firstMatch` you can do the rest (adding `Styles` and inserting to `mergeList`)

```
firstMatch.ifPresent(color -> {
  if(!color.getStyles().contains(styleid)){
    color.getStyles().add(styleid);
  }
  mergeList.add(lstExterior.get(idx));  
});
```